# Replace bootstrap icons with angular material icons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material instead of bootstrap  in previously created application and I don't know how to replace the bootstrap icons with angular material.Thank you for the help.

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini" color="warn"
    ng-repeat="question in quiz.dataService.quizQuestions"
    ng-class="{'btn-info': question.selected !== null, 'btn-danger': question.selected === null}" 
    ng-click="quiz.setActiveQuestion($index)">
    <span class="glyphicon"
        ng-class="{'glyphicon-pencil': question.selected !== null, 'glyphicon-question-sign': question.selected === null}">
    </span>
</md-button>
```

I am trying to replace glyphicon -pencil and glyphicon-question with

```
<i class="material-icons">help</i>
<i class="material-icons">star_border</i>
```

I tried this but didn't work

```
<i class="material-icons">
    {'help' = : question.selected !== null, 'star_border': question.selected === null}
</i>
```

Comment: Did you tried: `<ng-md-icon icon="help" style="fill: ..." size="..."></ng-md-icon>` in the place of `<i class="material-icons">help</i>`?

Comment: Thank you.I tried : <ng-md-icon ng-class="{'icon="help"': question.selected !== null, 'icon="star_border"': question.selected === null}"></ng-md-icon>   but didn't work

Comment: some error in console? I see that in the docs: https://klarsys.github.io/angular-material-icons/

Comment: No error. And just to be clear if I include the icons anywhere else is working fine. I just have a problem with the logic in the span class.

Comment: https://klarsys.github.io/angular-material-icons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant add icon style to span or i tags... instead of it you need use it nested:

```
angular.module('demoapp', ['ngMdIcons']);

<span>
    <ng-md-icon icon="help" style="fill: ..." size="..."></ng-md-icon>
</span>
```

i tag is for Google Icons and BTS

https://klarsys.github.io/angular-material-icons/

**Update** See the example:

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <div layout="row">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x" flex></i>
            <h1 class="md-title" style="color:white">Org Chart</h1>
        </div>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="left" ng-class="md-fling">
            <md-fab-trigger>
                <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-accent">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Actions
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_view_module_48px.svg"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-trigger>
            <md-fab-actions>
                <md-button aria-label="view" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        View Chart
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.read" ng-click="paneShowFn('read')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="add" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Add Chart
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_add_48px.svg" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.insert" ng-click="paneShowFn('insert')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="Settings" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Security Access
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_add_48px.svg" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.permission" ng-click="paneShowFn('permission')"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button aria-label="edit" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" style="color:black" ng-show="cDP.update" ng-click="paneShowFn('update')">
                    <md-tooltip>
                        Edit Chart
                    </md-tooltip>
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_edit_48px.svg" style="color:black"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-fab-speed-dial>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show me how to modify my span with the condition.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work: <ng-md-icon icon="{'help': question.selected !== null, 'star_border': question.selected === null}"></ng-md-icon>

Comment: Update with Code Example

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded one svg  icon and added the icon to one of my folders. I am trying to display the icon like: <md-icon md-svg-src="Images/Icons/star.svg"></md-icon>

Comment: But I don't see the icon.

Comment: I got the  error: angular.js:11756 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/documents/Website/QuizTest10/Images/Icons/star.svg. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: the problem is that you use a bad path for the, static http over https main web... you need resolver problem around the path or directory structure and if you do you could have icons to quickly view.